# 'sed' script to convert avr-asm to arm-gnu comments

Tags: assembly, sed, arm, comments

I want to convert every occurrence of a ';' into '@', but only if it is not quoted (discard the quotes in this line). The reason behind it:

Assembly language syntax of arm-asm has ';' as the comment sign and everything after a ';' is a comment. Despite of something like ';' or ";".

I suggest the following 'sed' script as a solution and would like to put it to discussion, in case I overlooked something:

File s:

```
s/^\([^(;\'\")]*\)\(;\)\(.*$\)/\1@\3/
```

File testcase:

```
;
  ;
;**********;****
  ';'
  ";"
';'
";"
ABC r1,';'
ABC r1,";"
; ";" ';'
;;;
```

Usage:

```
$ sed -f s testcase
@
  @
@**********;****
  ';'
  ";"
';'
";"
ABC r1,';'
ABC r1,";"
@ ";" ';'
@;;
```

---

I found that e.g.

```
        .include "stm32f407.s"        ; target register defines
        .set    PLLP, (DIVP - 2) / 2        ; some other comment
```

doesn't pass the test.

---

So hopefully this makes it now:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -e "s/^\([^(;\'\")]*\)\(;\)\(.*$\)/\1@\3/" -e "s/^\([^;]*\)\(;\)\(.*\)/\1@\3/"  $1
```

***Caveat***: the script works for [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) sed (e.g., [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS)), not GNU sed.

Comment: This is a subject of *[Perl / Unix One-liner Cage Match, Part 1](https://www.perl.com/article/perl-one-liners-part-1/)* (perl.com, 2021-05-12), subsection *"Skip some matches"*.

Answer (score 3):

With Perl (which is more portable than sed, provided the Perl interpreter is available)

```
perl -pe 's/(?:\x27;\x27|";")(*SKIP)(*F)|;/@/'
```

- `(?:\x27;\x27|";")(*SKIP)(*F)` any text satisfying `(?:\x27;\x27|";")` will not be changed, `\x27` is single quotes in hexadecimal format
- `|;` specify what should be changed as an alternate
- use the `g` flag if you want to replace all such occurrences
- use `perl -i.bkp` if you want in-place editing (just `-i` if you don't want a backup)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(["'\'']);\1/\1\n\1/g;s/;/@/;y/\n/;/' file
```

Replace all `;` between quotes or double quotes, with newlines.

Replace the first occurrence of `;` with `@`

Replace all newlines with `;`.

N.B. To replace all occurrences, use:

```
sed -E 's/(["'\'']);\1/\1\n\1/g;y/;/@/;y/\n/;/' file
```

This solution might work with all sed versions:

```
sed -Ee 'G
        :a
        s/(["'\'']);(\1.*(.))/\1\3\2/
        ta 
        s/;/@/
        :b
        s/(.)(.*\1)$/;\2/
        tb 
        s/.$//' file
```

It uses the fact an empty hold space appends a newline i.e the `G` command appends a newline, which can be captured and used in substitutions.

Comment: Thanks, but your examples both don't work. They should leave ; in quotes or double quotes untouched at any rate as well as ; already being in comments.

Comment: @Krischu are you using GNU sed?

Comment: I'm using macOS (OpenBSD) sed. Thanks. Your scripts worked both when using GNU sed (tried them both under UBUNTU)